# Simple HTML Dom getting different value

Tags: php, html, dom, woocommerce, scrape

I have a distributor and I want to add all of his products to my site using scrape method because he has no xml file. I have copied the same code which I used before for a different site, it doesn't work well.

My strategy is to find all product links in a category and then find all product attributes in all product links seperately and add them into database in woocommerce. I will repeat this process for all of the categories.

My code to get and insert datas is like below;

```
include ("../wp-load.php");
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
include 'function.php';
$url = $_POST['url'];
$kategori1 = $_POST['kategori1'];
$kategori2 = $_POST['kategori2'];
$kategori3 = $_POST['kategori3'];
$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = file_get_html($url,false,$context);

$count=0;
foreach($html->find('div[id=urunresim] a') as $element){
   $product = file_get_html('http://isiksilver.com/'.$element->href,false,$context);
   foreach($product->find('span[class=yazilar]',1) as $kod);
   foreach($product->find('span[class=yazilar]',3) as $gram);
   foreach($product->find('img',53) as $image);

$thumb = 'http://isiksilver.com/'.$image->src;
$thumb_name = basename($thumb);
$fiyat = str_replace(" GR", "", $gram)*8.5/1.8;
$my_post = array();
$my_post['post_title'] = $kod->innertext;
$my_post['post_content'] = '<table>'.$kod.' Ateş Kehribarı Tesbih</table>';
$my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
$my_post['post_author'] = 1;
$my_post['post_type'] = 'product';

// Yazıyı veritabanına ekle
$the_post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$image_data = file_get_contents($thumb);
$filename = $thumb_name;
if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))
$file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
else
$file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
$attachment = array(
'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename ),
'post_content' => '',
'post_status' => 'inherit',
'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename )
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $the_post_id );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

set_post_thumbnail( $the_post_id, $attach_id );

add_post_meta( $the_post_id, 'total_sales', '0' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_downloadable', 'no' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_virtual', 'no' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_regular_price', $fiyat );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_sale_price', $fiyat );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_base_currency_price', $fiyat );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_base_currency', 'TL' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_tax_status', 'taxable' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_tax_class', '18' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_purchase_note', '' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_weight', '' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_length', '' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_height', '' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_width', '' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_sku', $kod );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_variant_description', '' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_product_attributes', 'a:0:{}' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_sale_prices_dates_from', '' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_sale_prices_dates_to', '' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_price', $fiyat );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_sold_individually', 'yes' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_manage_stock', 'yes' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_backorders', 'no' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_stock', '5' );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_featured', 'no' );

wp_set_object_terms( $the_post_id, $brand->plaintext, 'yith_product_brand' );
wp_set_object_terms( $the_post_id, (int)$kategori1, 'product_cat', true );
wp_set_object_terms( $the_post_id, (int)$kategori2, 'product_cat', true );
wp_set_object_terms( $the_post_id, (int)$kategori3, 'product_cat', true );

$count++;

}      
echo $count.' ürün eklendi<br>';
```

It adds all products to db with the same name (and the value is different from what it should be). I can get correct value from single product page with below codes;

```
$product->find('span[class=yazilar]',1);
$product->find('span[class=yazilar]',3);
```

But it can't get the correct value in foreach (I tried to remove foreach and it gets correct value but it adds only first product into db and doesn't add meta datas this time).

How can I resolve tihs?

Comment: "because he has no xml file": if that's your distributor/partner, I am sure you can find a better way to exchange data than you having to scrape their site. Why not ask them for a db dump or a CSV export, etc?

Comment: @Gordon Let me explain. He is a local manufacturer and I met him last week. I asked him for products or data as you mentioned but he has no internet site also. He gave me that address and told that he can manufacture all products in this site. So my real partner is not that site.